# What Game Engine/Platform to use in order to Write Once and Deploy Everywhere?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Basically, I want to design a strategy game, where most of the game will be spent in menu areas and making "decisions" (like a Tycoon style game), however, there will still be some graphics, and I would prefer 3D, but if not possible, can resort to 2D. The graphics aren't user controlled, but the moving objects will be the result of the "decisions" the players make.

I really just want to write it once, and have it run on the following Platforms:

```
Windows Desktop
iOS (iPhone, iPod, iPad)
Android Phones (not strictly required)
```

(any other platforms would just be a bonus, but at the absolute minimum, all i really want is Windows Desktop and iOS [iPhone, iPod, iPad]).

Now, I don't want to learn objective-c or any other languages which i may have no use for in the future, I really just want to be able to program in Visual Studio (VB.Net or C#, since I can convert from vb.net to c# I will just be writing it in vb.net).

Is it possible to write in vb.net/c# and deploy to all these platforms? I heard of MonoTouch, so i can convert from vb to c# but is this seemless or difficult to do? Do I have to learn and write in another language in order to make tweaks to make it work on the iPhone or Android? So, with MonoTouch, can I still use XNA or is there a different engine that I need to learn/use with Visual Studio?

Alternatively, if I cannot do this all in VB.NET or Visual Studio, what programming language and/or graphics engine should I learn in order to be able to write once and deploy everywhere that is relevant? (So, not fussed about Linux, Mac's or other less used OS's).

Right now, I haven't learnt XNA but am wondering if I should or need to, or if i should learn another engine & language. Basically, I don't really know what I need to learn/know in order to be able to write once and deploy on Windows Desktop, iOS (iDevice's) and maybe Android. So, my question really is, what do I need to learn in terms of both the programming language and game/graphics engine. Right now I know VB.NET and would prefer to use what I know, but if not possible, then am prepared to learn another language & engine combination to be able to achieve what I want, if this is what I need to do, I would like to know what language & engine I need to learn.

Comment: Did you just say Linux and Mac machines are junkware? That doesn't leave much...

Comment: Not VB and not C# - so no answer, but a comment: LUA is multiplattform for game-development. "Well known" games like "hedgewars" and "ultrastar deluxe" are afaik implemented in lua.

Comment: Could we cut down on the inflammatory rhetoric please? I don't care if you like Obj-C as a language, but there's no need to call it "nasty", just like there's no need to call Linux and Mac "junkware". Please, act like an adult, and people might be inclined to give you adult answers. Especially if you also take responsibility like an adult, and do some research yourself, and are willing to acquire new skills where necessary

Comment: What you're asking is basically "how can I make a game that runs everywhere, without having to learn anything new". Does not compute.

Comment: @jalf what did you not understand about my question? I clearly stated that I am WILLING TO LEARN a new language and a new engine, and i CLEARLY ASKED what language/engine I would be willing to learn. Also, I've spent 2 days googling this stuff, you'd be suprised at how many platforms assume someone that strolls onto their website knows what they do and how to use their tools. I spent ages on Unity website to find out they dont have a programming language, it isn't a framework you can use in VS, but a damn design tool you can import dlls with (in a hacky kinda way). Pls read Q's before flaming.

Comment: You CLEARLY said, and I quote, "Now, I don't want to learn objective-c or any other nasty languages, I really just want to be able to program in Visual Studio (VB.Net or C#, since I can convert from vb.net to c# I will just be writing it in vb.net)." Oh, and Unity certainbly isn't "a damn design tool you can import dlls with". Please stop flaming before you ask Q's.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Actually, i've spent 2 days googling this stuff, google is not a search engine you can ask specific questions to, unfortunately, despite spending days googling this stuff, I still dont have an answer, & have come to SO as a last resot (i only come here as a last resort). & maybe you never got the memo, but SO is infact everyones research assistant. If you didnt like the question or if I rubbed you the wrong way, dont answer it, in fact, dont even comment with remarks that dont make sense, of all the negative things you could have said, u picked the only one that was wrong. damn.

Comment: Oh, and drop the attitude, please. You're the one asking others for help. Making a good impression is quite important in such a situation. You might think I'm a meanyhead, but the thing is, I don't depend on being perceived as friendly and huggable, because I'm not the one asking for help. (And no, SO is *not* your personal research assistant. It appears **you** did not get the memo, even though you were given a link to it just above. And "googling for two days" is not the same as "researching a programming problem".

Comment: @jalf stop being a troll. of course i prefer to write it in vb/c# because these are the languages i know, did you not read the rest where i said, if these options are not possible, that I am happy to learn other language/engine combo, and if i need to learn other language/engine combo, i asked what this language and engine combo would be, twice. Did you not read that? If you did, why would you suggest that I was not "willing to acquire new skills where necessary"...? Maybe you're not a troll, maybe you just missed it.

Comment: Read the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Pose this exact question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ and you may get better results.

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder: I wonder if it could be something to do with you calling other languages and platforms "nasty" and "junkware" for no apparent reason. I wonder if it could be anything to do with the fact that you spend two days googling, and then go to SO to get others to do your basic background research for you. I wonder if it could be anything to do with the fact that as of today, you apparently only know one language: VB.

Comment: Here's the thing: people who are willing to learn, learn. They are *always* learning. People who are willing to learn don't generally insult technologies they don't know. *Saying* you're willing to learn, but *behaving* like someone who is not makes it kind of a hard sell, don't you think?

Comment: No, will **you** listen to me? I gave you advice. You didn't like the advice. That's your problem. But do you *honestly* think that your behavior in these comments, *regardless of what you think of me*, is going to help you get better answers? You don't personally need **my** help, no, but you **do** need the help of the SO community. Behaving like a spoiled brat in front of said community probably isn't the smartest thing you could do. As for "chip on their shoulder", or "arrogant", well, it takes one to know one. Perhaps you should look at your own behavior?

Comment: @jalf there you go again putting words in my mouth, i actually know a lot more than VB but the other things i've learnt over the 12 years are not relevant to game dev. Perl/CGI, JavaScript from the netscape days, asp.net & MVC etc etc didn't need a mention. Secondly, what makes you think i expected others to do my research? hell no, i'm asking to find people that ALREADY KNOW, OR ALREADY HAVE FACED THIS SITUATION - of course, you know this, but are looking for things to poke me with, its really pathetic of you to do this and act like a child.also, what i think of macs is my opinion, not a fact

Comment: @jalf what i think of macs or objective-c is me expressing my opinion, i dont state it as a fact, nor do i impose this on others, it is also not an insult. people have different opinions, you need to accept that. you still havent explained why youve twisted my words, & have actively gone looking for things to poke me with, only to bring up the weakest things which you surely knew wouldnt stand. I thinkg this behaviour of yours is really upsetting & makes the rest of the community here look bad simply by asociation. If you have emotional problems, you should look up "emotional healing therapy".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good option for this is [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/).  It allows you to develop a game, and from a single source, publish to PC, Mac, iOS, Android, and other platforms.

It does support C# development (which was one option you listed), though it typically is handled via their own editor instead of within Visual Studio.  That being said, they do [support Visual Studio as the code editor](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25671/how-to-set-visual-studio-2010-as-default-script-ed.html) for projects.

Comment: thanks for your input, i'm curious to know how one can interact with the objects in unity using an external code editor, do the objects show up in intellisense? I heard you can compile dll's and import them into unity, how do the dll's know how to access the objects in unity? Do you think its practical as a system when they work together? thanks.

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder I haven't used it for a while, but yes, you do get full intellisense when you use VS as your editor, provided you setup things correctly (that link shows that).  It's based on mono, which supports .NET assemblies fairly well, so objects you create are "normal" .NET objects.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it out (but I tried MonoTouch - and it worked like a charm), but [MonoGame](https://monogame.codeplex.com/) could be the solution for you.

It's C# with XNA for deploying everywhere. For MonoTouch there was a rather hacky way to work with VisualStudio - but for my part it was a good way to work with MonoDevelop (a really good OpenSource-IDE btw.).

Answer (score -1):

C# was invented by Microsoft for use on their products and XNA and Visual Studios are again  microsoft development tools, if you're looking to place this across several platforms it might be less headache to consider Java or C++. also as said above, go look for this info it is more then readily available after some 5 minutes of search

Comment: C# was invented for a lot of reasons, and it's certainly not a Microsoft-exclusive language.

Comment: didn't say exclusive. Just stating that it will be alot harder to do software for IOS, Android, AND Windows in C#. Especially if they don't want to rewrite large sections for each version

Comment: @darthsheldon im not sure what queries your using, but ive been on google for the past 2 days looking up this stuff, i surely haven't found an answer to my question, this is why i asked here. + when ppl say its deployable everywhere, it usually means you have to do code tweaking on each of those platform and languages before deploying, since you can't know in advance which areas of the code you'l need to tweak (apart from UI differences) I will have to learn each language for each platform if the porting requires platform specific tweaking. was hoping to learn at most 1 additional language.